# Maximizing directional derivatives?

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus

Alright, I'm trying to fine the gradient of the function and the maximum value of the directional derivative.

$$z = \frac{y}{(x^2 + y^2 )}\text{ at }(1,1)$$

So far, I've gotten the following values for partial derivates, but I can't guarantee they are correct:

$$F_x = \frac{-2xy}{(x^2 + y^2 )^2}$$
$$F_y = \frac{-2y^2}{( x^2 + y^2 )^2} + \frac1{x^2 + y^2}$$

GradientF(x,y) = \frac{-2xy}{( x^2 + y^2 )^2 + (-2y^2)/( x^2 + y^2 )^2} + 1/( x^2 + y^2 )^2}$$
GradientF(1,1) =  -2/4i + (-2/4)j + (1/2)k = <-2/4, -2/4, 1/2>
||F(1,1)|| = <-2/4, -2/4, 1/2> (1/sqrt(3/4))

I get <-2/3, -2/3, 2/3> but this is wrong...

I should be getting <1/2, 0> at max value of 1/2 according to my friend who ceases to explain anything to me.

Any help?  Thanks.

Comment: Your partial with respect to $x$ is missing a factor of $\frac2{x^2+y^2}$...

Comment: How?  I just did it again and got the same answer?

Comment: Maybe you can post your solution in detail? Then we can debug...

Comment: OK, mind editing in my mistakes that I make when formatting?  Sorry, I'm new here =(

Comment: Edited in.  Now for formatting

Comment: Nono, I meant what steps did you take to go from, say $\frac{\partial}{\partial x} \frac{y}{(x^2 + y^2 )^2}$ to your result?

Comment: I actually mis-wrote that.  I edited it now, it wasn't squared on the bottom.  Sorry!

Answer (score 2):

To evaluate partial derivatives of a function $f(x,y)$, you fix one of the variables as the constant, and derivate with respect to the other variable. For instance, if you're trying to find, say, $\partial_x f$, treat $y$ as a constant; you can temporarily change $y$ it for $a$ if you wish so as to see it more clearly.

The maximum value of the directional derivative will occur in the direction along the gradient vector (at a given point). This maximum value will be the norm of the gradient vector (at that point) -- just review the definition of directional derivative, it's a dot product between the gradient vector and a unit vector that gives the "direction".

Comment: I've got the first part, it's just the second one that's giving me problems.  Can you elaborate?  Thanks!

Comment: @jtm22: Where's that $k$ coming from? Don't you have two variables only? The gradient should be a two-dimensional vector. You just have to calculate its norm.

Comment: You're right.  Now I have the <-1/2, 0> but I just don't know where to go after that?  Then I calculate the norm?

Comment: Yes, indeed, you just calculate the norm. But it may be worthwhile if you check *why* you do that.

Comment: I don't think so...I calculated the norm and I got -1.  I should be getting (1/2).  Can you verify?

Comment: @jtm22 You got the norm of (-1/2,0) to be -1? Norms are non-negative, and it wouldn't be +1 anyway. Check again.

Comment: Can you verify that I'm doing:  <-1/2, 0> multiplied by (1/sqrt((-1/2)^2 + (0)^2))?

Comment: Do the dot product of the vector with itself, then take the square root.